# Filter some records based on date range

Tags: sql-server

I have below tables structures,

**Trans Table:**

```
Trans_Id(PK)     User_Id(FK)       Arroved_Date
________________________________________________
1                   101             05-06-2016
2                   101             12-06-2016
3                   101             20-06-2016  
4                   102             06-06-2016
5                   103             10-06-2016
6                   103             25-06-2016
```

**Table2:**

```
Id(Pk)           User_Id(Fk)       Start_Date    End_Date     Is_Revoked
_________________________________________________________________________
1                  101              01-06-2016   15-06-2016     1
2                  101              10-06-2016   15-06-2016     0 
3                  103              05-06-2016   20-06-2016     0
```

I want to filter out the transaction, if the Approved_Date is not between the users Start_Date and End_Date of table2.

```
If is_revoked = 1 then it should not consider.
```

**Expected Result:**

```
Trans_Id
________
1
3
4
6
```

Comment: Why transid 2 is not shown in the output? For both transid 1 and 2 you have userid 101, and in join either both has to be selected or both has to be rejected rite?

Comment: because Trans_id 2 is approved on 12th june. In Table2 Start date and End date is 10-06-2016 to 15-06-2016. Since Approved date is on 12th, it should be filtered.

Comment: how abt trans 4,that 102 userid is not matching with table2?!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT A.Trans_ID
FROM TransTable A JOIN Table2 B
ON (A.User_Id = B.User_Id)
WHERE B.Is_Revoked = 1 OR A.Approved_Date NOT BETWEEN B.Start_Date AND B.End_Date
```

Answer (score 0):

This resolves you,

```
SELECT Trans_Id FROM TRANS AS A JOIN TABLE2 AS B ON A.[USER_ID]=B.[USER_ID] 
WHERE B.IS_REVOKED=0 AND ARROVED_DATE NOT BETWEEN B.START_DATE AND B.END_DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

there are basically two condition you want to meet.

1. if `is_revoked` is equal to 1 then ignore the row from the result..
2. if  `Approved_Date` is between `start_date` and `end_date` then dont consider then also ignore this from the result.

So this can be easily done using join.

```
SELECT A.Trans_ID
FROM TransTable A, Table2 B
WHERE B.Is_Revoked != 1 AND A.Approved_Date NOT BETWEEN B.Start_Date AND 
B.End_Date
```

As far as I understand from the expected result that you mentioned. you really dont' care if the `User_id` matches or not.